# Screen scraper for Ubuntu?

Tags: linux

Is there a [screen-scraper](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/screen-scraper) for Linux?

Comment: Are you looking for OCR (Optical Character Recognition, Image To Text) or Screenreaders (which are reading the screens to you)?

Comment: Please [see here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/280475/how-can-instantaneously-extract-text-from-a-screen-area-using-ocr-tools) for a screenshot OCR solution on Ubuntu/Linux.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, I don't really know what you mean by 'screen-scraper', but check [Freshmeat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freecode):  [the tool *screenscraper*](http://freshmeat.net/projects/screenscraper/) and [search for *scraper*](http://freshmeat.net/search?q=scraper&submit=Search).

Answer (score 1):

I am not exactly sure what you mean. However, if you are talking about [screenshots](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/screenshots) or capturing what is on the screen, Ubuntu has a very good built-in program.

On the menu, expand `Applications > Accessories > Take Screenshot` to launch it.

Answer (score 0):

if you need to "take a photo" of your screen or a window, then there should be the built in app as William mentioned - in GNOME desktop environment.

If you use KDE, then there is Ksnapshot. In both cases, you can try to press PrintScreen (prt sc or PrtScr) on your keyboard and the app should start.

If you need to extract text from image, then look for OCR apps like GOCR etc.